# Bug report: Search miscounts number of results, or won't display all results

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search, https

I did [a search for `user:25554 is:a [automata]`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A25554+is%3Aa+[automata]).  The resulting page claims “19 results”:

[image: Search results, top of page 1]

The page lists 15 results, and offers a second page:

[image: Search results, bottom of page 1]

Clicking on the link to page 2 of the results brings up [this page 2 of the results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=user%3a25554%20is%3aa%20[automata]), which reports “19 results: Your search returns no matches”, contradicting itself:

[image: Search results, page 2]

If there are 19 results, it should disgorge all 19.  If there are fewer than 19 results, it should not report that there are 19.  If there are 15 or fewer, it should not offer a link to a second page of results.  In no case should the search offer a link to an empty page of results.

Comment: This bug seems to be related to my use of the HTTPS-everywhere browser extension. The bad behavior disappears when I disable the extension.  I am leaving the bug report up in case it is of interest to the SE developers.

Comment: I added the HTTPS tag due to your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

We don't fully support the HTTPS Everywhere extension or HTTPS connections across the network. Yet. If this is still an issue once we do the latter, please let us know.